# Pass php session variables to javascript and back to php

Tags: javascript, php, session-variables

I have the following code which basically the user enters a number and presses the search button which makes PHP lookup the value and return any records from the MySQL database (approval1.php?go). This works as expected so I left that code out. What I am trying to do is after the user reviews the records they can be approved by clicking the link. That link runs some javascript which takes the number entered from the PHP session. Once the javascript takes the user to the next page which also works I want it to pass that value back to php so that it may be displayed in the next form. How can this be done and also is there a simpler way to do this? Everything I find is either from php to javascript or the other way around. I can't seem to find anything that shows how to get the session variable back.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<?php 
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head><title>Title</title></head> 
</head>
<p><body>
<h3>Search:</h3>
<p>Please enter the reference number of the record you would like to review:</p>
<form method="post" action="approval1.php?go" id="searchform">
<input type="number" name="REF_NO">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function approve() {
    passSession("<? echo $_SESSION['REF_NO']; ?>");
    $.get("approval2.php");
    return false;
}
</script>

<a href="http://location/example.com" onclick="approve();">Approve Request</a>


</form>
</body>
</html>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is just this: Pass the approval as a GET variable.

```
<a href="http://location/approval2.php?ref_no=<?php echo $_SESSION['REF_NO']; ?>&approval=1">Approve Request</a>
```

Then, in the approval2.php page, receive those GET variables:

```
$ref_no = $_GET['ref_no'];
$approval = $_GET['approval'];
```

Comment: Hi Peter. All it does is give me the number 1 as the $ref_no variable and nothing for $approval

Comment: I fixed a mistake - should be $_GET['ref_no']. Unfortunately, this is not easy to make a fiddle of, since it's two pages. You should put the first block of code in your HTML and the second in your PHP of the receiving page (approval2.php). Really, though, if this REF_NO is just a single session variable, there's no since in passing it at all. Just pass the approval and obtain the REF number from session. Your receiving page would be: $approval = $_GET['approval']; $ref_no = $_SESSION['REF_NO'];

Comment: Ok, please accept the answer if that works for you. I obviously need the points. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
<?php
<script type="text/javascript">
var vars=passSession("<? echo $_SESSION['session_id']; ?>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a hidden input field:

```
<form method="post" action="approval1.php?go" id="searchform">
<input type="number" name="REF_NO">

<input type="hidden" name="php_sess" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['REF_NO']; ?>">

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">


<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function approve() {
    passSession("<? echo $_SESSION['REF_NO']; ?>");
    $.get("approval2.php");
    return false;
}
</script>

<a href="http://location/example.com" onclick="approve();">Approve Request</a>


</form>
```

So when you submit a form, `$_REQUEST['php_sess']` will be populated in php.

Comment: The form is submitted when the user clicks search. After that he clicks approve to approve which runs the javascript to take you to the next php file so could that cause it to fail? Also how do I output it in the next for using $_REQUEST['php_sess'] or $_REQUEST['REF_NO'] or $_SESSION['REF_NO']? I just tried the first one and it doesn't show the value.

Comment: Basically, you want `$SESSION['REF_NO']` in approval2.php, right ? You can pass the data in `$.get();`.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Yes thats right. So if I understand correctly all I need to do after on approval2.php is to just echo $_SESSION['REF_NO']; right? Or would I have to get it back from $.get()?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use a $_SESSION variable, here. When you lookup something at approval1.php?go and you return some DB records, also return the id  REF_NO of that record (e.g. use JSON to send two things at a time). Then, on approval, send this id again, simply by GET. To me, this much more consistent and prevents you from failure e.g. **when users browse with two tabs**, etc.

Example for approval1.php

```
<?php

$result = json_encode(array(
  "REF_NO"  => $id,
  "content" => $content
);

echo $result;
?>
```

Then, access the JSON in Javascript. Use the REF_NO node to prepare your approval link.

Comment: you mean replace the php script for search with json?

Comment: No, I mean the php script for search should return a JSON. What do you return at the moment? html or text?